# is the a better way? on instantiating objects for SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, object, instantiation

when I made an SQLite database for an Android app I made a helper class that does not extend any other class.  it is just to set up the database, in this example it is called PlayGame.  it has a private class inside it shown here:

```
 private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
```

when I use the database for any reason in the main UI class called SQLiteExample I have to create an instance every time like this,

```
PlayGame entry = new PlayGame(SQLiteExample.this);
            entry.open();
            entry.createEntry(name, hits);
            entry.close();
```

I am creating many instances of this database class called PlayGame in the other Activity class.  Like in most all of my methods have to make instances to do the required function like read information into or out of the database.

so I read in best practices of android documentation that creating instances is heavy on memory and is best avoided. If this is the case is there a better way to do this?  and does my example look like a bad use of memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use singleton for every instance you want to use. instead of create a new instance of any object you will use the same object.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern